# dijkstra implementation I have found (Python)

Tags: python, dijkstra

I have used this implementation:
(*http://geekly-yours.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/dijkstra-algorithm-python-example-source-code-shortest-path.html*) 
..for dijkstra's shortest path algorithm. I am making a program which returns the shortest path with postcodes. It puts all of the postcodes into a graph like they have done in the implementation.
The whole postcode part works.

However,
At the end of the program I have added to the src and dest with a inputs asking what the user would like the starting point(src) and final destination(dest) to be.

```
print("Enter start postcode: ")
src = input()
print("Enter destination postcode: ")
dest = input()
print(graph)
dijkstra(graph,src,dest)
```

It only works when the src or dest is the same as one of the postcodes I have previously entered into the graph and it wont let me assign a new/different src or dest.

Can someone help?
If this isn't clear enough I can copy all of my code in. (trying to keep it less cluttered as possible.)

Comment: Are you expecting it to be able to find paths between postcodes that aren't in the graph?

Comment: yes, I want to be able pass the program a starting point and an ending point. And find the quickest route through all of the other postcodes.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm has absolutely no way of knowing where new postcodes are in relation to the ones that are in the graph (how would it?!). You'll need to attach them as new nodes in your graph with links to nearby existing ones.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, could you show me? would be much appreciated.

Comment: The real question is - why are you using Dijkstra for this at all? If you have postcodes and you want distances, the better way would be to just calculate GPS coordinates and use those directly...

Comment: To find the shorest route between multiple destinations. It is a program for a project. Needs to have some kind of meaty algorithm.